# Silverlight Control not working THAT good

Tags: silverlight, controls

I have this problem that I have a little menu with a croll bar.. inside there's a couple of items with checkboxes.. On iterating through these checkboxes I get a null error.It seems like this is caused whenever a checkbox is not part of the visible space of the menu thingy.. Like Silverlight only initiate the checkbox when you scroll down so it is visible..

Anyone have any idee how to get around this?

Comment: How are you iterating through the items? Can you post a snippet of your code? Possible that you're not just getting the checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

When iterating thru the checkboxes, try adding a check to see if you're actualy dealing with a checkbox and not something else that's in the elementtree.

```
Loop thru children
  if(child is CheckBox){ 
  // Do what you want with the checkbox
  }
```